# Universal aplication ipad version don't work at iPad but yes at simulator

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

After finisghing us iphone application we decide to do a port to iPad. For that we select universal to the settings of the project and create all the viewControllers ended with ~iPad. In the simulator all works fine but when I compile it and deploy to the iPad it takes the iPhone views. Any idea of why it works in simulator but not in deploy mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying  a lot of options, the way to solve this problem is add ~ipad to all the ipad XIB and ~iphone to all the iphone XIB. For me it works when both of the XIB family has his extension name...

I would say to that iPhone simulator is not case sensitive with the name but once is deployed to the iOS device yes. I hope it helps!